# Unable to save a multimedia component by core service

Tags: web8, core-service

When we use WEB 8 core service to save a multimedia component, it will popup below error:

> Unable to save this multimedia component. Error message is: Unable to get file size of 'FS_168228f3-e70b-4e10-8bec-4434cae2f3f7'Could not find file 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\0-231-65552_2f04ad91-9694-4452-bd8b-e506e5201540.tmp'.

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you checked if the Window eventlog on the server contains more details? Also could it perhaps be related to the size of the file you are trying to upload, how large is it and does it work with smaller files? Please edit your question and provide these details.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to upload/save your MM Component?